# bash: echo: write error: Interrupted system call

Tags: bash

I want to generate a sorted list with all 8-digit numbers — from 00000000 to 99999999.
I typed in the shell:

```
f() {
 while IFS="" read -r line; do
   for i in {0..9}; do 
       echo "$line$i";
   done;
 done
}

echo | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | tee result.txt | wc -l
```

response is

```
bash: echo: write error: Interrupted system call
bash: echo: write error: Interrupted system call
bash: echo: write error: Interrupted system call
99998890
```

Why have I got these three errors and malformed result.txt ?

I use

GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)

Linux kernel: 4.19.0 #2 SMP Thu Nov 1 15:31:34 EET 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I can't help but feeling this way of doing it would not be more efficient than `seq -w 0 99999999`.

Comment: Then the question is incomplete/incorrect/badly written or something else. Because the script (when completed with the `}`) works correctly. @GAD3R

Comment: Note: I can trigger these errors almost on demand. They often appear when I resize my `konsole` window. Such resizing is almost sufficient in my case, yet not necessary.

Comment: I can remove the `| tee result.txt`, and still get the error.

Comment: Another note: external executable (`/bin/echo` in my case) instead of `echo` builtin makes the function immune (or at least less prone) to this issue.

Comment: Every time you see an error like `Interrupted system call` or the made-up `Short write` it's a **bug** in the program spouting it. In this case, the bug in bash was already [reported](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-01/msg00031.html). `EINTR` is not really an error, but a way to indicate that a system call should be re-done. Ignoring `SIGWINCH` is in no way acceptable, because bash should know in real time how large the terminal is for its line-editing and completing to work reliably.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it is immune because `/bin/echo` doesn't install any handler for `SIGWINCH`, and the default disposition for that signal is "ignore". `bash` does install a handler for `SIGWINCH` without setting `SA_RESTART` in its flags, which would've prevented it from interrupting syscalls (in fact, the readline does set it, but bash is overriding readline's handler).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specific `write error: Interrupted system call` error is generated when the console window size is changed while the script is being executed.

Doing a:

```
 trap '' SIGWINCH
```

will avoid it.

Note that a

```
 seq 99999999 >result.txt; wc -l <result.txt
```

Will be both faster and will avoid the `SIGWINCH` issue.

Comment: So what is going on?, why have I not seen this before?, Why is a write error, the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a bug **[1]** in `bash`, and it doesn't happen only on `SIGWINCH`, but also on any signal for which a trap was set:

```
{ pid=$BASHPID; trap : USR1; (sleep 1; kill -USR1 $pid) &
         printf %0100000d 1; } | sleep 3600
bash: printf: write error: Interrupted system call
```

It happens because `bash` fails to either a) set its signal handlers with `SA_RESTART` (except for the `SIGCHLD` handler), or b) handle the `EINTR` when calling `write()` in the `printf` and `echo` builtins.

`EINTR` ("Interrupted system call") is not a way to indicate an error condition, but a hack which allows the programmer to combine blocking reads/writes/etc with the handling of signals in the main loop. It should never be leaked to the user.

This bug doesn't show up too frequently because it's quite a feat to get the right conditions in place: the `write()` should be done by a *builtin* (not by an external command), it should fill up the pipe buffer (the reader at the other end should be *much* slower or not reading from the pipe at all *but still alive*), and the script should use traps or the terminal window should be resized.

And because of diverse implementation artifacts, this only affects interrupted `write()`s, not `read()`s or `open()`s (as eg. the blocking `open()` of a named pipe/fifo).

**[1]** a form of this was already [reported](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-01/msg00031.html) some time ago.